# Call function with defined types

Tags: function, postgresql, jdbc, types

I created my own Postgres function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction(
param_val1 varchar(255),
param_cal2 VARCHAR(255), 
param_val3 VARCHAR(255),
param_val4 current_category,
param_val5 current_type,
param_val6  VARCHAR(255),
param_val7 bigint,
param_val8 text )
```

I want to call it with jdbc:

```
callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{call myfunction(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

  callableStatement.setString(1, "item1");
  callableStatement.setString(2, "domain1");
  callableStatement.setString(3, "indicator1");
  callableStatement.setString(4, "PROPERTY");
  callableStatement.setString(5, "STRING");
  callableStatement.setString(6, "on");
  callableStatement.setLong(7, 1396983600);
  callableStatement.setString(8, "testing");
```

But I get:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function addindicators(character varying,     character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, bigint, character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add     explicit type casts.
  Position: 15
```

`current_category` and `current_type` are enums. Do I need to create java enums and then use setObject(#, Object)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to define the function as taking `text` / `varchar` parameters and cast to your `enum` types inside the function. Example Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction( ..., param_val4 text, ...)
...
DECLARE
  _param_val4 current_category := param_val4::current_category;
  ...
BEGIN
...
```

But there is probably a way in Java to call this function without explicit types (I don't know of). If you can send untyped string, (string literals of type `"unknown"`) for the enums, Postgres finds the best match for the function automatically.

Comment: @EliMiller: Casting is simple. I added a code example.