# Compute an aggregated tsrange from a set of entries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-programming, dynamic-sql, range-types

I am trying to compute a aggregated `tsrange` from a set of row that I extract from an SQL query. Problem is that I keep getting errors that the input parameter is not being passed in.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE range_merge(anyrange)
(
    sfunc = range_merge,
    stype = anyrange
);

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS aggregate_validity(entity_name regclass, entry bigint);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aggregate_validity(entity_name regclass, entry bigint) returns tsrange AS
$$
DECLARE
    result tsrange;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('select range_merge(valid) from %s where entity_id = %U', entity_name, entry) into result;
   return result;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I do:

```
select * from aggregate_validity(country, 1);
```

I get an error stating that the entity name and entry do not exist. It does not seem to parameterize the input into the statement properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function:

```
EXECUTE format('select range_merge(valid) from %s where entity_id=%U',entity_name, entry) 
into result;
=>
EXECUTE format('select range_merge(valid) from %I where entity_id=%s',entity_name, entry) 
into result;
--%I for identifier, %s for value
```

Call:

```
select * from aggregate_validity(country, 1)
=>
select * from aggregate_validity('country', 1);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=90cbb5c9c1e6af7314255db97179096a)**

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE range_merge(anyrange) (
   SFUNC = range_merge
 , STYPE = anyrange
);

-- DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS aggregate_validity(entity_name regclass, entry bigint);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aggregate_validity(entity_name regclass, entry bigint, OUT result tsrange)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT range_merge(valid) FROM ' || entity_name || ' WHERE entity_id = $1'
   INTO result
   USING entry;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT aggregate_validity('country', 1);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1fe26ec03224ab476e9943a529159cc0)*

The call does not need `SELECT * FROM`, as the function returns a single value per definition.

I used an `OUT` parameter to simplify (`OUT result tsrange`). See:

- [Returning from a function with OUT parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762734/returning-from-a-function-with-out-parameter/20763195#20763195)

Don't concatenate the `entry` value into the SQL string. Pass it as *value* with the `USING` clause. Cleaner, faster.

Since `entity_name` is passed as `regclass`, it's safe to simply concatenate (which is a bit cheaper). See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Plus, missing quotes and incorrect format specifiers, as Lukasz already provided.

Your custom aggregate function `range_merge()` has some **caveats**:

1. I wouldn't name it "range_merge", that being the name of the plain function [`range_merge()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE), too. While that's legal, it still invites confusing errors.
2. You are aware that the function `range_merge()` *includes* gaps between input ranges in the output range?
3. `range_merge()` returns NULL for any NULL input. So if your table has any NULL values in the column `valid`, the result is always NULL. I strongly suggest that any involved columns shall be defined as `NOT NULL`.

If you are at liberty to install additional modules, consider [**range_agg**](https://github.com/pjungwir/range_agg) by Paul Jungwirth who is [also here on Stackovflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122087/paul-a-jungwirth). It provides the superior function `range_agg()` addressing some of the mentioned issues.

If you don't want to include gaps, consider the [Postgres Wiki page on range aggregation.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Range_aggregation)

I would probably ***not*** use `aggregate_validity()` at all. It obscures the nested functionality from the Postgres query planner and may lead so suboptimal query plans. Typically, you can replace it with a **correlated or a `LATERAL` subquery**, which can be planned and optimized by Postgres in context of the outer query. I appended a demo to the fiddle:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ac3af0e906be798671f4c9433951367b)*

Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Comment: execute a nested select statement within a select statement? 
I am bit confused how to do sO

Comment: `country` does not work
SELECT aggregate_validity('country', 1);
`country` is seen as text

Comment: @kafka: I added some more details how to use a subquery instead. Also, `SELECT aggregate_validity('country', 1);` should work just fine, as demonstrated in both fiddles. Note that `'country'` is an **untyped string literal** here. If you pass a value of type `text`, you need to cast explicitly! Like:  `SELECT aggregate_validity(country_variable_as_text_type::regclass, 1);` See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19943343/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005922/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676871/939860

Comment: Also consider the additional module `range_agg`. I added pointers above.

Comment: I have at this stage already ensured for gaps an overlaps, hence this does not need to taken care of -  but thanks for the reminder.